# Relay module and DC motor not working

Tags: relay, dc-motor, esp8266

I there,
I've got this code running on an ESP8266

```
#include <Arduino.h>

//Pins connected to the relays
int relay1 = 12;
int relay2 = 14;
int relay3 = 5;
int relay4 = 16;

void forward();
void reverse();
void stop();

void setup() {
    //Set the relay pins as output
    pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(relay2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(relay3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(relay4, OUTPUT);

    //Motors off
    digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(relay3, HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(relay4, HIGH);

    //Initialize serial monitor with 9600 baud
    Serial.begin(9600);
    delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
    forward();
    delay(2000);
    reverse();
    delay(2000);
}

void forward() {
    stop();
    delay(20);
    digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(relay3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(relay4, HIGH);
}

void reverse() {
    stop();
    delay(20);
    digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(relay3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(relay4, LOW);
}

void stop()
{
    digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(relay3, HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(relay4, HIGH);
}
```

And this is my wiring [image]

I noticed that one of my motors wasn't working properly when I checked with a Multimeter the middle terminal on the 1st and 2nd relay (counting right to left) the Multimeter only registered +9V or 0V.
When I tried on the other 2 relays I got +9V and -9V

Am I doing something wrong? Is the module dead in anyway?

Comment: What are the relay board LEDs telling you? Your code's relay pin assignment looks odd: 12, 14, ***5***, 16. Something out of sequence there?

Comment: The LEDs are correct one time relay 1 and 4 ON while others are OFF and the other time relays 2 and 3 are ON while the others are OFF

Comment: Proceed logically. Connect the multimeter common to battery negative. Monitor each of the common pins on the relays. They should switch from 0 to +9 V. Then repeat with multimeter common to battery positive. They should switch from 0 (when the relay is feeding +9 V because at this time there will be no difference in voltage between the meter leads) to -9 V (because 0 V is 9 V **below** the 9 V the meter common is connected to).

Comment: I didn't quite understand in each way is this different in the way I tested and saw that on relay 3 and 4 the voltage is either 9V or -9V (depending if the code is on forward or reverse) and on the other 2 relays the voltage is either 9V or 0V

Comment: OK. It wasn't clear to me how you were measuring. The 0 V case means that one of the two contacts isn't making properly but doesn't tell you which one. My method will show you which one is faulty.

Comment: After I find which one isn't making contact, what are my options?

Comment: Proceed logically. Switch only that relay and listen for it clicking. If it does then you have a contact problem. If it doesn't then you have a coil or circuit board problem. In that case you have four identical circuits to compare. Have fun!

Comment: Well, I've tested each relay going ON and OFF and all of them make the switching sound

Comment: You should have identified the faulty contact by now.